# Microsoft Graph API returns invalid_role_scope_combination when trying to get a profile photo

Tags: java, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I need to get profile photos from MS Graph API and upload them to Azure Blob storage.

I am doing this with MS Graph Java SDK. Here us the code for retrieving the photo `InputStream`:

```java
InputStream photoInputStream = graphServiceClient.users().byUserId(adUser.getId()).photo().content().get();
```

When this call is made, I get the following exception:

```
com.microsoft.graph.models.odataerrors.ODataError: invalid_role_scope_combination
    at com.microsoft.graph.models.odataerrors.ODataError.createFromDiscriminatorValue(ODataError.java:36) ~[microsoft-graph-6.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.kiota.serialization.JsonParseNode.getObjectValue(JsonParseNode.java:210) ~[microsoft-kiota-serialization-json-1.0.4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.kiota.http.OkHttpRequestAdapter.lambda$throwIfFailedResponse$0(OkHttpRequestAdapter.java:672) ~[microsoft-kiota-http-okHttp-1.0.4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.kiota.ApiExceptionBuilder.<init>(ApiExceptionBuilder.java:26) ~[microsoft-kiota-abstractions-1.0.4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.kiota.http.OkHttpRequestAdapter.throwIfFailedResponse(OkHttpRequestAdapter.java:671) ~[microsoft-kiota-http-okHttp-1.0.4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.kiota.http.OkHttpRequestAdapter.sendPrimitive(OkHttpRequestAdapter.java:341) ~[microsoft-kiota-http-okHttp-1.0.4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.graph.users.item.photo.value.ContentRequestBuilder.get(ContentRequestBuilder.java:60) ~[microsoft-graph-6.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.graph.users.item.photo.value.ContentRequestBuilder.get(ContentRequestBuilder.java:46) ~[microsoft-graph-6.4.0.jar:na]
...
```

I have added the following permissions to application registration:
[image]

Here is the code for configuring MS Graph API credentials if this helps:

```java
private static final String DEFAULT_MS_GRAPH_SCOPE = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";

@Bean
public GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient() {
    ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId(clientId)
            .clientSecret(clientSecret)
            .tenantId(tenantId)
            .build();

    return new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, DEFAULT_MS_GRAPH_SCOPE);
}
```

Comment: Could you include what `API permissions` you granted in the App registration by editing your question with Portal image?

Comment: Added the picture with permissions.

Comment: You are using client credentials flow in the code but granted permissions of **Delegated** type. Could you please grant `User.Read.All` or `User.ReadBasic.All` permission of **Application** type and check if it works?

Comment: Could you check whether you can fetch that user's profile photo via [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) or not like this https://i.imgur.com/9famZjK.png?

Answer (score 0):

I registered one Azure AD application and granted `User.ReadBasic.All` permission of **Application** type as below:

[image]

To retrieve the **profile image** of user and upload it to Azure blob storage, you can make use of below modified java code:

```java
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential;
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.TokenCredentialAuthProvider;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.User;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.GraphServiceClient;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobClientBuilder;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClientBuilder;

public class AzureADUserAuth {
    final String clientId = "appId";
    final String tenantId = "tenantId";
    final String clientSecret = "secret";
    final List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");

    // Azure Blob Storage settings
    final String connectionString = "storacc_connection_string";
    final String containerName = "profile-photos"; // Name of your blob container

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            AzureADUserAuth azureADUserAuth = new AzureADUserAuth();
            azureADUserAuth.fetchAndUploadProfilePhoto();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void fetchAndUploadProfilePhoto() throws Exception {
        // Authenticate with Azure AD
        ClientSecretCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(clientId).tenantId(tenantId).clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .build();

        if (null == scopes || null == credential) {
            throw new Exception("Unexpected error");
        }

        TokenCredentialAuthProvider authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, credential);
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider).buildClient();

        // Fetch user profile photo as InputStream
        InputStream profilePhotoStream = graphClient.users("userId")
                .photo()
                .content()
                .buildRequest()
                .get();

        // Read the profile photo content into a byte array
        byte[] photoBytes = profilePhotoStream.readAllBytes();

        // Create InputStream from byte array
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(photoBytes);

        // Upload profile photo to Azure Blob Storage
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(connectionString)
                .containerName(containerName)
                .buildClient();

        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient("profile_photo.jpg");
        blobClient.upload(inputStream, photoBytes.length, true);

        // Close the InputStream when done
        profilePhotoStream.close();

        System.out.println("\nProfile photo uploaded to Azure Blob Storage.\n");
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Azure Storage account blob container where profile photo uploaded successfully like this:

[image]